# PHP syntax error when installing pear on mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying (with some problems) to install pear on my system, Mac osX 10.6.6

PHP works ok, as apache and mysql.

On /usr/local I followed the instructions:

```bash
$ curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

$ php go-pear.phar
```

and I get

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected BOOL_FALSE in /private/etc/php.ini on line 1050
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my php.ini.

Comment: My suggestion is to go to line 1050 of php.ini to determine what configuration flag is erroring out.

Comment: Pleas show your php.ini about 1050 line.

Comment: What are the instruction you followed?

Comment: I thought 10.6.6 shipped with pear pre-installed anyway?

Comment: Didn't install pear manually, but I had a similar problem on a line 972 in a windows php.ini which was only a comment. Copying another example php.ini in temporarily solved the problem. Hope I can solve it properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out, so I'm posting the solution for future references.

My PHP.ini was corrupted, so I had to go back to PHP.ini.default and redo all the changes.

Then I changed:

```
phar.require_hash = Off
```

as suggested in other posts,

and finally added:

```
detect_unicode = Off
```

Bingo! 
From what I understand, the Zend engine Unicode checker is enabled by default on osX 10.6 and it causes a conflict when opening a .phar

Reference: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42396
Credits to matt/technosophos for posting the workaround.

Comment: Just copying php.ini.default and adding the /usr/local/share/pear include path fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I checked php.ini first thing when I saw the error.

This is what it looks like around line 1050:

---

```
[Phar]

; http://php.net/phar.readonly

; phar.readonly = On

; http://php.net/phar.require-hash

;phar.require_hash = On

;phar.cache_list =
```

---

(still scratching my head ...)

Comment: I played around with it. I tried phar.require_hash = Off as per other posts but I get the same error

Comment: Keep going up and down, look for a line without a semicolon (;) in front — those are all commented out.

Comment: ok, this is getting too complicated for me. I *thought* I had tried phar.require_hash = Off -- I did change the PHP.ini as I've done before with TextWrangler and saved, and restarted apache. But then I run phpinfo() and discovered that this change (and many others that I did before) are not there. Looks like apache is reading the wrong php.ini file. Don't know what to do at this point :((

Comment: I finally figured it out. Posting the solution for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Mac I just spent few hours trying to figure out why PEAR wasn't installing on my OSX 10.6.0 setup (Apache and PHP 5.3.3 were pre-installed without PEAR). Trying to follow the usual instructions:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ sudo php go-pear.phar
```

... would just result in a string of question marks ('??????'), and no further error messages even though I had enabled display all errors.

In the end the problem was solved by reinstalling PHP5 from [macports](http://www.macports.org/) (the current version is 5.3.5). Once I had done that, 'sudo php go-pear.phar' worked without any problems.